# Elixir: How to get bit_size of an Integer variable?

Tags: binary, elixir, bitwise-operators, elixir-iex

I need to get the size of bits used in one **Integer variable**.

like this:

```elixir
bit_number = 1
bit_number = bit_number <<< 2
bit_size(bit_number)   # must return 3 here
```

the `bit_size/1` function is for 'strings', not for integers but, in the exercise, whe need to get the size of bits of the integer.

I'm doing one exercise of compression of an book (Classic Computer Science Problems in Python, of Daivid Kopec) and I'm trying to do in Elixir for study.

Comment: Why `bit_size(bit_number) == 3`? As far as I know it should return `2` as it is exactly `2` aka `0b10`.

Comment: Oh god, yes.. i wrote the 1... tks. my mistake i will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
(iex) import Bitwise
(iex) Integer.digits(1 <<< 1, 2) |> length
2
```

but I'm sure there are better solutions.

(as @Hauleth mentions, the answer here should be 2, not 3)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and technically most flexible) option is to use the fact that `n` will have exactly `ceil(log_b(n))` digits in base `b`. So what we are looking for is:

```
ceil(:math.log2(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many times you can divide it by two:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def bits_required(0), do: 1
  def bits_required(int), do: bits_required(int, 1)
  defp bits_required(1, acc), do: acc
  defp bits_required(int, acc), do: bits_required(div(int, 2), acc + 1)
end
```

Output:

```elixir
iex> Example.bits_required(4)
3
```